# I want to use background-image property of css class for a div in a webpage, but it is not working properly

Tags: asp.net

he guys
i am using background-image property of a css class in div but it is not working properly.
my code is:

.div_background
{
    background-image:none|url('C:\Users\NT\Desktop\THEME5.png') | inherit ;
}

Answer (score 0):

The URL cannot be a local path.  You need to reference a path that the client web browser will be able to access (such as http://mysite.com/app/images/THEME5.png)